# Why there is a difference in time between node.js server and mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, time

In my mongoDB database I have a document which attribute 'dia' is a Date filled with:

> 'ISODate("2018-09-07T20:00:00.000Z")'

The problem came when I try to get this document in my node.js server. Currently I'm using mongoose and when I do a model.findById('5b9d04c728c1640c07bb054f') it returns the object fine, except for the fact that the attribute 'dia' has the following value:

> 'Fri Sep 07 2018 17:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03)'.

Does anyone know why there is a difference between the date saved in my database and the one made by mongoose when I try to get the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that my database is storing every document in GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) and my server is running in my local timezone which is GMT(-3). To use the correct date for querying mongoDB, I used moment.js with the following parameters:

```
var date = moment.utc(dia).format();
```

getting as result 'date = 2018-09-01T20:00:00Z', which is the same time as in the database.

UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) is the same as GMT, but it is being using nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely it is saved as GMT and read in GMT-3 timezone. It may well be that node.js assumes that it gets GMT datetime and formats it according to your locale. You may want to either read the date with desired locale (instead of the default GMT) or print it in the locale GMT which should fix the difference.